# optimize sum by every 2 elements in list

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
mylist = [0.01, 0.09, 0.04, 0.16]
```

I want to take the sum every two elements, so my result will be:
`[0.1, 0.2]`

I figured this solution:

```
chunks = [mylist[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(mylist), 2)]

temp = []
for i in chunks:
    s = 0
    for j in i:
        s += j
    temp.append(s)

print(temp)
```

`[0.1, 0.2]`

but I was wondering if there is a better solution avoiding the 2 for loops.

Comment: Is it possible to have an odd number of list items? e.g. [1,2,3]?

Comment: @MukeshIngham:No, it will be even.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not simply use the `sum(..)` builtin:

```
temp = [sum(mylist[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(mylist), 2)]
```

This is a one-liner that clearly is more Pythonic. Furthermore it is probably more efficient since here you do not store all slices into memory first, etc. but you directly calculate the sum.

Answer (score 5):

Some people might consider it an overkill, however once you go into calculations over arrays of numbers, numpy is your friend. It enables you to make such calculations in a **readable and efficient** manner.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0.01, 0.09, 0.04, 0.16])
# reshaping the array to a 2D array, and summing over the columns
x.reshape((x.shape[0]/2,2)).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Small improvement:

`x.reshape((-1, 2)).sum(axis=1)`

Explanation: Reshape can also take "-1" as a dimension size, which indicates that that dimension size will be automatically inferred form the shape of the array and the size of the other dimensions

Answer (score 1):

```
map(sum, zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2]))
```

For lists of odd length, use `zip_longest` instead

```
from itertools import zip_longest as zipl
map(sum, zipl(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2], fillvalue=0))
```

Comment: There is a problem if the number of elements is odd since in that case the last element will not be counted: `[1,2,3]` will produce `[3]`, not `[3,3]`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if that's an issue, use `itertools.izip_longest` (Python 2.7) or `itertools.zip_longest` (Python 3.x) with `fillvalue=0`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (Will work for both even and odd lengths):

```
import itertools as it    
[sum(r) for r in it.izip_longest(mylist [::2], mylist [1::2], fillvalue=0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`iteration_utilities.grouper`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/grouper.html):

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import grouper
>>> mylist = [0.01, 0.09, 0.04, 0.16]
>>> [sum(group) for group in grouper(mylist, 2)]  # or "list(map(sum, grouper(mylist, 2)))"
[0.09999999999999999, 0.2]
```

That the first value isn't 0.1 is because of floating point arithmetic, the other solutions here are similarly affected.

This should be as fast as the other approaches, maybe even faster (except for the numpy-solution).